# Log files are still created even when general_log is OFF - MySQL (MariaDB)

Tags: logs, mariadb-10.4

I have a MySQL server (10.4.21-MariaDB) installed by the XAMPP stack on ubuntu.
I notice in the mysql folder (/opt/lampp/var/mysql) several files:

- ip-172-31-14-21.err
- ip-172-31-14-21.log
- ip-172-31-14-21-slow.log

I want to disable that but then I noticed that `general_log` is OFF and no specific setting in `my.cnf` is relevant for those logs.

I tried to add `log = /dev/null` to the config but with no luck as this prevent mysql to start and  throwing an error.
Any ideas how I can disable those logs?

Comment: The `general_log` is a different feature, used to log *all* queries. Slow log logs long running queries and has it own config variables. And log/err is the "normal" app output of the server process - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log-windows.html

Comment: @jkavalik Is there away to shut down the process logging?

Comment: Afaik not entirely (it wants to report errors) but you can redirect it somewere else, check the link.